# What services that I can't use when I unsubscribe the mobile me?

Tags: mobileme

I've used mobile me(me.com) quite a while, but I happen to know and use [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com).

DropBox is much better than iDisk in terms of easy of use, size, speed, and many things. I'm considering discontinue to use mobile me to switch to 50G option of Dropbox ($100/year), but before doing that, I need to know what services that I cannot use.

I need to use, even though I can live without them.

- email web check.
- bookmark and other items sync

Can't I use them I unsubscribe the me.com? What are the paid services that me.com provide other than iDisk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Terms of Service](http://www.apple.com/legal/mobileme/en/terms.html) (number 10) you will not be able to use any of the services you are currently paying for after termination of subscription.

> Upon termination of your account you lose all access to the Service and any portions thereof, including, but not limited to, your Member Account (any Sub-accounts thereunder), Subscriber ID, email account, iDisk, domains, iChat account and MobileMe Gallery albums.